# Optimization of the formatting of several documents

Tags: formatting, templates

I need to create 60 documents with Russian-English phrases. I have these phrases in a plain text formar. Each document contains about 200 sentences and should look like this:

[image]
There is a rule that each group [Rus-Eng] should be on the same page. For that I want to use this code after each phrase:

```
 \pagebreak[2] %It indicates the location where the page might break
```

So I am thinking to do this job this way:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Arial} 
\usepackage{hyphenat}% Hyphenation rules
\hyphenation{ма-те-ма-ти-ка вос-ста-нав-ли-вать}% Hyphenation rules
\begin{spacing}{1.25}
\usepackage{color} 
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.60}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Андрей будет визажистом.} \\
\emph{\color{light-gray}\textit{Andrei will be a visagiste.}}
\pagebreak[2] %It indicates the location where the page might break

Будет ли Андрей стилистом? \\
\emph{\color{light-gray}\textit{Will Andrei be a stylist?}}
\pagebreak[2]%It indicates the location where the page might break

Нет, Андрей не будет стилистом. \\
\emph{\color{light-gray}\textit{No, Andrei will not be a stylist.}}
\pagebreak[2] %It indicates the location where the page might break

Будет ли Андрей парикмахером?  \\
\emph{\color{light-gray}\textit{Will Andrei be a barber?}}
\pagebreak[2] %It indicates the location where the page might break

Нет, и парикмахером он тоже не будет. Андрей будет визажистом. \\
\emph{\color{light-gray}\textit{No, he will not be a barber too. Andrei will be a visagiste.}}
\pagebreak[2] %It indicates the location where the page might break

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\bigskip % A vertical interval equal an empty line.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\textbf{Он будет жить в Санкт-Петербурге.} \\
\emph{\color{light-gray}\textit{He will live in Saint-Petersburg.}}
\pagebreak[2]%It indicates the location where the page might break

Будет ли Андрей жить в Москве? \\
\emph{\color{light-gray}\textit{Will Andrei live in Moscow?}}
\pagebreak[2] %It indicates the location where the page might break

Нет, он не будет жить в Москве. Он будет жить в Санкт-Петербурге. \\
\emph{\color{light-gray}\textit{No, he will not live in Moscow. He will live in Saint-Petersburg.}}
\pagebreak[2] %It indicates the location where the page might break
% ...
% About 200 sentences more
% ...
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

But I need to copy and paste a lot in each document. But it will to take a lot of time. Is there any way to optimize it to? Maybe make a template to uply it for all documents?

Comment: What's your input format?

Comment: @TeXnician now I have just 60 `.txt` documents (plain text). I am planning to use online editor (overleaf). And the output format should be `.pdf`

Comment: A txt file contains just a plain text like this: `Андрей будет визажистом.
Andrei will be a visagiste.
Будет ли Андрей стилистом?
Will Andrei be a stylist?
Нет, Андрей не будет стилистом.
No, Andrei will not be a stylist.
Будет ли Андрей парикмахером?
Will Andrei be a barber?
Нет, и парикмахером он тоже не будет. Андрей будет визажистом.
No, he will not be a barber too. Andrei will be a visagiste.

Он будет жить в Санкт-Петербурге.
He will live in Saint-Petersburg.
Будет ли Андрей жить в Москве?
Will Andrei live in Moscow?
`

Comment: Yes, all docs have a line breaks and an empty line also.

Comment: Well that would be a further approach for optimization. Maybe in addition to Steven B. Segletes' answer.

Comment: If you know how to program, you could write a simple script in Perl/Python/... that would automate adding the LaTeX code. In Linux, command line scripts in awk or sed may be able to do this.

Comment: In a good editor, you should be able to do the same thing, but you will need to do it 60 times.  For example: Search for the beginning of each line and replace with "{". Search for the end of each line and replace with "}\n". Search for "{}" and replace with "". Search for "\n\n{" and replace wtih "\n\n\\secttrans{\\textbf"

Comment: @dbwilson I am very new in programming. Which editor you would recomend me?

Comment: First, see if Overleaf can do regular expression search and replace. If not, have a look at jEdit. This is a great free editor that works on any OS. If you want to get serious you can use Emacs or Vi, but they will take more effort to learn (but if you spend a lot of time writing LaTeX code, it may be worth the effort).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will keep each translation on the same page, and will accommodate linebreaks.  I offer `\settrans[bold?]{}{}` as the vehicle.

EDITED to put all the formatting inside the macro definition.  Since the first line (Cyrillic) is sometimes bolded, I provide an optional argument to `\settrans`, such that any optional argument will make the cyrillic bold.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\stacktype{S}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\newcommand\settrans[3][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\let\tmp\relax\else\let\tmp\textbf\fi%
  \stackunder[0pt]{\parbox{\textwidth}{\strut\tmp{#2}\strut}}{%
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\strut\emph{\color{light-gray}\textit{#3}}\strut}}\par\smallskip}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Arial} 
\usepackage{hyphenat}% Hyphenation rules
\hyphenation{ма-те-ма-ти-ка вос-ста-нав-ли-вать}% Hyphenation rules
\begin{spacing}{1.25}
\usepackage{color} 
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.60}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\settrans[b]{Андрей будет визажистом.}
{Andrei will be a visagiste.}

\settrans{Будет ли Андрей стилистом?}
{Will Andrei be a stylist?}

\settrans{Нет, Андрей не будет стилистом.}
{No, Andrei will not be a stylist.}

\settrans{Будет ли Андрей парикмахером?}
{Will Andrei be a barber?}

\settrans{Нет, и парикмахером он тоже не будет. Андрей будет визажистом.}
{No, he will not be a barber too. Andrei will be a visagiste.}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\bigskip % A vertical interval equal an empty line.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\settrans[b]{Он будет жить в Санкт-Петербурге.}
{He will live in Saint-Petersburg.}

\settrans{Будет ли Андрей жить в Москве?}
{Will Andrei live in Moscow?}

\settrans{Нет, он не будет жить в Москве. Он будет жить в Санкт-Петербурге.}
{No, he will not live in Moscow. He will live in Saint-Petersburg.}

\settrans{Нет, он не будет жить в Москве. Он будет жить в Санкт-Петербурге.
Нет, он не будет жить в Москве. Он будет жить в Санкт-Петербурге.}
{No, he will not live in Moscow. He will live in Saint-Petersburg.
No, he will not live in Moscow. He will live in Saint-Petersburg.}
% ...
% About 200 sentences more
% ...
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

[image]